# Lenovo Miix 2 11 Touchpad not working with win 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

After updating from Win 8 to Win 10 the touchpad stopped working completely. It Works fine With an external mouse. Any solutions anyone?

Comment: Have you installed the latest Windows 10-compatible driver for your touchpad?

Comment: Lenovo support told me there wasn't any new driver for Windows 10 yet.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting Lenovo Support via the Online Chat function, and talking to Microsoft via Contact Support, I managed to figure out a fix for the issue.

With Lenovo, the technician wanted me to install an updated driver version, but there is none available on the site. However, while working on it, I and the tech discovered that the Synaptics Pointing Driver (roughly the name) in the Programs and Features Application is conflicting with the Windows 10 installation. Uninstall it, restart the computer, log in (with onscreen touchboard or a USB port mouse) and the touchpad will work.

If the problem crops up again, then the program reinstalled itself, (check Program and Features first), so repeat the steps.

Comment: It appears that you have a valid answer but cannot say much at this moment

Comment: This worked! I spoke with Lenovo support as wel, but the guy could only tell me there was no driver. I think I tried to uninstall before as well, but didn't have an USB-mouse on reboot so i t didn't work then. I'll see how long it takes before the driver gets installed automaticly. Thank you!